# Network setup not showing up so I can't create plugin on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, networking, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin for wordpress. However, the plugin panel is not showing up, so I read that its because the Network Setup menu item also is not showing up. I followed the instructions on this website:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_2:_Allow_Multisite

I just completed step 2, but it didn't make any difference. The Network Setup menu is still not showing up. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That means, you are neither an admin for single WP site nor a super-admin for a WP multisite.

Read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Answer (score 0):

What kind of plugin do you want to create?

And what is the necessity of network setup in a plugin creation?

I guess you want to create a multisite network in wordpress!

You need to define `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Just a really simple hello-world plugin. I think the network setup is required to see the plugins on wordpress. I already defined the "WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', TRUE" in the wp-config file, but that didn't help

Comment: Developing a plugin does not require "WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', TRUE" at all!!

Comment: So why am I unable to see a plugin tab on the menu, such as in this link: http://corpocrat.com/2009/12/27/tutorial-how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: when I go to [myname].wordpress.com/wp-admin/network/plugins.php I get the error msg "the requested page does not exist"